# Nextjs Footer rendering at top of page - only for index.js page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am currently working a site building react components using nextjs as a framework.  I also had this issue with vanilla react build as well, but on every page, the footer renders fine, outside of the index.js page, where it renders above all the page specific content, right at the bottom of the navbar.

Here is the _app.js file:

```
import Navbar from './Nav';
import Footer from './Footer';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import Script from 'next/script';
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {


  useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://static.elfsight.com/platform/platform.js" data-use-service-core defer />
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is the index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
//import styles from "../styles/globals.css"
import Footer from './Footer'
import SecondLanding from './SecondLanding'
import FirstLanding from './FirstLanding'
import ThirdLanding from './ThirdLanding'
import FourthLanding from './FourthLanding'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default class extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
        <>
        <Head>
            <title>Title_here</title>
        </Head>
          <div className='main_container background_photo font-face-gm'>
            <div className="body">
              <div className="wrapper">
                    <FirstLanding />
                    <SecondLanding />
                    <ThirdLanding />
                    <FourthLanding />
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
```

Here is the expected behavior:
[image]
Here is the unexpected behavior:
[image]

I know this is a common issue i've seen posted on other forums but I was unable to fix this through those threads and am back after hours of tinkering.

I don't think this is necessary, here here is the footer code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../styles/Footer.module.scss';
import { router } from "next/router";
import Contact from '../../public/images/contact.png'
import Image from 'next/image';

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <footer className={styles.footer}>
                <div className={styles.container}>
                    <div className={styles.firstContainer}>
                        <div className={styles.contactContainer}>
                            <Image className={styles.contactImg} src={Contact} width={32} height={32} alt='cash' />
                            <h3 className={styles.contactHeader}><strong>Contact Us!</strong></h3>
                            <p className={styles.contactInfo}>
                                (651)472-2736<br/>
                                sales@spiesscarpet.com</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.infoContainer}>
                        <div className={styles.waves}>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave1}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave2}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave3}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave4}></div>
                        </div>
                    <div className={styles.topContainer}>
                        <ul className={styles.menu}>
                            <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/about"><p className={styles.link}><strong>About</strong></p></Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/services"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Services</strong></p></Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/contact"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Contact</strong></p></Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/testimonials"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Testimonials</strong></p></Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/faq"><p className={styles.link}><strong>FAQ</strong></p></Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bottomContainer}>
                        <p style={{ opacity: 0.75 }}>&copy;2023 Nick Spiess | All Rights Reserved</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} href='/quote' passHref>
                        <button
                            className={`${styles.btnMd} ${styles.navButton}`}
                            onClick={() => router.push('/quote')}
                        >
                            <strong>Get a Free Quote!</strong>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                </div>
            </footer>


            <footer className={styles.mobileFooter}>
                <div className={styles.container}>
                    <div className={styles.infoContainer}>
                        <div className={styles.waves}>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave1}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave2}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave3}></div>
                            <div className={styles.wave} id={styles.wave4}></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.topContainer}>
                            <ul className={styles.menu}>
                                <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                    <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/about"><p className={styles.link}><strong>About</strong></p></Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                    <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/services"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Services</strong></p></Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                    <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/contact"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Contact</strong></p></Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                    <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/testimonials"><p className={styles.link}><strong>Testimonials</strong></p></Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className={styles.menu__item}>
                                    <Link className={styles.menu__link} href="/faq"><p className={styles.link}><strong>FAQ</strong></p></Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} href='/quote' passHref>
                            <button
                                className={`${styles.btnMd} ${styles.navButton}`}
                                onClick={() => router.push('/quote')}
                            >
                                <strong>Get a Free Quote!</strong>
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bottomContainer}>
                            <p style={{ color: 'white', }}>&copy;2023 Nick Spiess | All Rights Reserved</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </>
    );
};

export default Footer;
```

css:

```
.bottomContainer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobileFooter {
  display: none;
}

.contactHeader {

  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
}

.infoContainer {
  margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline; /* Add display flex */
  justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
}

.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactImg {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.contactContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contactInfo {
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;

}

.firstContainer {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.topContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: -5vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  background: #3586ff;
  min-height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top:0vh;
}

.social-icon,
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}



.social-icon__item,
.menu__item {
  list-style: none;
}

.firstContainer {
}

.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navButton {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  border: solid rgb(102, 176, 255) 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navButton:hover {
  background-color: #3586ff;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid white 3px;
}

.social-icon__link {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.link {
  text-align: center;
}

.link:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.social-icon__link:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.menu__link {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.981);
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.menu__link:hover{
  color: white;
}

.menu__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0 0px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}


.wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/wQZVxxk/wave.png");
  background-size: 1000px 100px;
}

.wave#wave1 {
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: animateWaves 8s linear infinite;
}

.wave#wave2 {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 10px;
  animation: animate 8s linear infinite !important;
}

.wave#wave3 {
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  bottom: 15px;
  animation: animateWaves 5s linear infinite;
}

.wave#wave4 {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 20px;
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateWaves {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    background-positon-x: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position-x: -1000px;
  }
  100% {
    background-positon-x: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .footer {

}

.firstContainer {
  width: 25%;
}

.contactInfo {
  text-align: center;
}

  .infoContainer {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

}

/* Media query for smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobileFooter {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .mobileFooter .container {
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .container {
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 0vh;
    margin-top: 15px;
    
  }

  .buttonContainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;

  }

  .menu__item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .menu__link {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .topContainer {
    display: inline;
  }

  .firstContainer {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobileFooter {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #3586ff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0; /* Add this line */
  }

  .firstContainer,
  .infoContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navButton {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem; /* Adjust the font-size value as needed */
    padding: 8px 16px; /* Adjust the padding values as needed */
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It can be related to the css classes used in the index.js file like main_container, wrapper, etc.

Comment: Banging my head for days solving it and just removing that fixed it on the spot.  Thank you, sir.